Can I store photographic slides in the fridge?
My work has a collection of slides from the 1960s and 70s to preserve. We are digitizing all of them and creating inventory records, and then we want to store them in the safest way possible. We wonder if putting them in sealed bags in a fridge is a good idea or if the risk of moisture is more dangerous than fluctuating temperatures (which we have elsewhere in the office). We currently have them in archival slide boxes, but I read that storing them horizontally is preferable, so any thoughts on that are appreciated as well.
To note, we have this fridge available and that's what we'd use. There would of course be no food in the fridge ever, and in theory we would never open it other than to check if everything is ok. Any thoughts on this are much appreciated! I read the other threads about slide preservation but nobody mentioned a fridge so I thought I'd ask.
Many thanks in advance!

Are the slides Kodachrome? I have Kodachrome slides from my father that are 70 years old and are in perfect condition. No special storage precautions.

The gold standard reference for this kind of thing was always 'The Permanence and Care of Color Photographs' by Henry Wilhelm, available now as a free download. I'd also recommend taking a look at Kodak's technical publication 'Storage and Care of
KODAK Photographic Materials'.

Refrigerators are quite dry, 30-50%, since humidity of the air is removed near the cooling element, where it condenses as drops and it is removed. This is good, it avoids fungal growth:

Prolonged exposure to relative humidity in excess of 60 percent can
lead to fungal growth on gelatin emulsions irrespective of the type of
film base.

Too dry (< 15%) is also an issue, it makes the gelatine brittle, but refrigerators don't get that low.
Check the recommendations:



Film Type
Temperature
Relative Humidity (%)




B&W on cellulose estar base
25 degree C maximum (77 degree F)
20 - 50


B&W on polyester base
25 degree C maximum (77 degree F)
20 - 50


Color on cellulose ester base
10 degree C (50 degree F)
20 - 30


Color on polyester base
10 degree C (50 degree F)
20 - 30



So you might not need any sealing.
Your worry comes from another aspect: keep in mind that air being cooled  will INCREASE its relative humidity so once inside, quickly move them around to replace the outside air near the slides, humid, with the air from the fridge itself, already dry.
If you use a sealed bag, especially sealed when outside the fridge at room temperature, condensation is guaranteed.

Can't say anything about slides but can say that you shouldn't care about moisture in the fridge because all modern fridges have dehumidifiers which work naturally because water condenses on the cold parts of fridge and is then extracted and evaporated. Therefore the air is dryer (in terms of absolute humidity) in the fridge than outside. Whether that's good for the slides or not I do not know.

If you are correctly sealing the slides in a bag before putting them in the fridge, then you are fixing the humidity of air in that bag to whatever it was when you sealed the bag1.  Thus, there is no additional risk of moisture to the slides.
If you keep the slides outside of the fridge, I don't know if normal daily temperature variations will affect the substrate of the slides.  But keeping them in the fridge will ensure a stable temperature, and that is generally a Good Thing™ when preserving items.
1. I used to work in the research center of a paper company.  In order to standardize tests on paper samples to national/international requirements, all work was performed in a room controlled at 23°C and 50% humidity.  If the paper samples needed to be moved around, or maintenance was being performed on the testing room, the samples were simply sealed up in plastic bags until they were needed again.  This kept them at 50% humidity.  They were also allowed time to settle to the 23°C temperature before the bags were opened.

This is a very wrong approach: the outside air, with its humidity, will condens into droplets, also on the film, when cooled down.
